# Making a list of numbers without a loop in r

Tags: r, list

I want to make a `list(1,2,3,4,5,....111)`.

`list(1:111)` makes a one element list with a vector of `1:111` in the first element.

How can I make it so each number is its own element?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For each number to be its own list element, you want `as.list()`

```
as.list(1:111)
# [[1]]
# [1] 1
#
# [[2]]
# [1] 2
#
# [[3]]
# [1] 3
#
# ...
```

Comment: Clearly eval/parse is the way to go: `eval(parse(text = paste0("list(", paste(1:111, collapse = ","), ")")))`  I think we can all agree that this is the superior, more readable way to write this code.

Comment: Hahaha, clearly.  The most characters, the best.  Of course, I would go with `seq_len(111)` to increase the amount of code and because I'm just a `seq_len()` kind of guy.

Comment: Is this improved enough? Or should I go deeper: `eval(parse(text = paste0("list(", paste(rev(seq(length(seq_len(111)), 1)), collapse = ","), ")")))`